# jQuery Ajax in ASP.NET sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have been trying to get this to work reliably on my VS2010 web emulator, desktop browser (IE 10) and my android browser (android 2.3.4). Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't in each of those browsers.

Here is my head html:

```
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/SPA1.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here is the relevant html:

```
<!-- Start of page_1---------------------------------------------------------------->
<div data-role="page" id="page_1" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Mobile Stop Check</h1>
</div>


<div data-role="content" id="select" data-theme="a">

<label for="select_choice_line" class="select">Select Line:</label>
<asp:DropDownList id="select_choice_line" runat="server"  data-theme="a"  AutoPostBack="false">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" >Select Line</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>


<label for="select_choice_juris" class="select">Select Jurisdiction:</label>
<asp:DropDownList id="select_choice_juris" runat="server"  data-theme="a" AutoPostBack="false"
      DataSourceID="sdsJuris" DataTextField="jurisddescription" 
      DataValueField="jurisddescription" AppendDataBoundItems=True>
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Jurisdiction</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

<label for="select_choice_dir" class="select">Select Direction:</label>
<select name="select_choice_dir" id="select_choice_dir" data-theme="a">
  <option Value="0">Select Direction</option>
  <option value="E">EAST</option>
  <option value="N">NORTH</option>
  <option value="S">SOUTH</option>
  <option value="W">WEST</option>
</select>

<label for="select_choice_sot" class="select">Select Street of Travel:</label>
<asp:DropDownList id="select_choice_sot" runat="server"  data-theme="a" AutoPostBack="false"
      DataSourceID="sdsSOT" DataTextField="onstreet" DataValueField="onstreet" 
      AppendDataBoundItems=True>
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Street</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

<label for="select_choice_cross" class="select">Select Cross Street:</label>
<select name="select_choice_cross" id="select_choice_cross" data-theme="a">
  <option Value="0">Select Cross Street</option>
  <option>La Cienega</option>
  <option>Wilshire</option>
  <option>La Brea</option>
</select>

<label for="select_choice_ss" class="select">Select Stopside:</label>
<select name="select_choice_ss" id="select_choice_ss" data-theme="a">
 <option Value="0">Select Stopside</option>
 <option value="F">FAR</option>
 <option value="I">INTERSECT</option>
 <option value="M">MIDBLOCK</option>
 <option value="N">NEAR</option>
</select>

<p><a href="#home_page" data-role="button">Back to Home Page</a></p>    
</div><!-- End of p1 content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
    <h4>Page 1</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!--end of page_1---------------------------------------------------------->
```

Here is my ajax piece:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getValues() {

    var str = "13:15499^";
    str = str + "01:" + $("#select_choice_line").val() + "^";
    str = str + "08:" + $("#select_choice_juris").val() + "^";
    str = str + "02:" + $("#select_choice_dir").val() + "^";
    str = str + "04:" + $("#select_choice_sot").val() + "^";

    str = str + "05:" + $("#select_choice_cross").val() + "^";
    str = str + "07:" + $("#select_choice_ss").val() + "^";

    //be sure to take last caret off or add on ifcopying this line
    str = str + "05:" + $("#select_choice_auth").val();

    addNewRecord(str);

}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addNewRecord(strnewrecord) {

        var send = "{'strnewrecord':'" + strnewrecord + "'}";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/AddNewRecord_WM",
            data: send,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#data").append(msg.d);
                $("#txt_log").append(msg.d);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is my code behind:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function AddNewRecord_WM(strnewrecord As String) As String
    Dim dt As String = Now.ToString
    Dim html As String

    If strnewrecord = Nothing Or strnewrecord = "" Then
        html = "<p>Transmission DateTime: " & dt & "</p>"
        html = html & "<p>Data String: None</p>"
        html = html & "<p>Return Msg: No data selected</p>"
        html = html & "<p>--------------------------------</p>"
    Else
        Dim arrFromClient As Array = strnewrecord.Split("^")
        'Dim arrToDB As Array '= ExpandClientData(arrFromClient)

        'Dim msg As String '= AddNewRecord(arrToDB)
        Dim msg As String = AddNewRecord(arrFromClient)



        html = "<p>Transmission DateTime: " & dt & "</p>"
        html = html & "<p>Data String: " & strnewrecord & "</p>"
        html = html & "<p>Return Msg: " & msg & "</p>"
        html = html & "<p>--------------------------------</p>"

    End If

    Return html

End Function
```

If it gets to the code behind it will do the data insert reliably.

When I couldn't get the ajax to work reliably, I went to a postback method just to send the data to the DB, but I couldn't get the button to click reliably on my phone browser. Now I'm back to async.

First, is my ajax code correct? Once the data string gets to my webmethod, the codebehind works reliably.

Second, are there issues with jQuery that cause click issues? Would a keyup event be better?

Thanks for any direction towards a solution.

Comment: Check your document mode when using Internet Explorer (press F12 to bring up the developer tools). jQuery 2.x only works with IE 9 or higher. So you have to make sure you tell the browser to use the correct document mode.

Comment: set your control CientIDMode Property to static when page is rendered asp.net changes the IDs